# Unlock and Unistalling the Sample Data - Blog plugin in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x

I want to Uninstall the Sample Data - Blog plugin, but the plugin can't be remove when it's stil locked. How to unlock the Sample Data - Blog plugin in Joomla 4?

Comment: Thank you for your question.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Since 4.0 all core extensions are locked and cannot be uninstalled. Their files are re-introduced after updates anyways. But you can still disable most core extensions, including the sample data plugin.